# Transform Express.js api route into Nexjs api

Tags: reactjs, api, express, next.js

I have this Express API route:

```
const router = require("express").Router();

router.get("/:jobId/:format", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { jobId, format } = req.params;

    if (format.toLowerCase() === "json") {
      const transcript = await req.asyncClient.getTranscriptObject(jobId);
      res.json(transcript);
      return;
    }

    if (format.toLowerCase() === "text") {
      const transcript = await req.asyncClient.getTranscriptText(jobId);
      res.send(transcript);
      return;
    }
    res.statusCode(500).send(`Invalid format ${format}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  req.io.emit(`transcript`, req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

module.exports = router;
```

and i want to convert it to an Nextjs API route.
The part i don't understand the most is this line:

```
router.get("/:jobId/:format", async (req, res) => {...
```

How do i get `/:jobId/:format` in Nextjs?

Comment: If you use the same naming convention as above, then It'll be `req.query.[property]`: [dynamic routing documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes). If you use `[...slug]` to capture all params, then it'll be `req.query.slug[propertyIndex]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like that:

- create a file inside /api called [...jobId].js

inside the file you can access /jobId/format like that

```
const { jobId } = req.query
```

it if *format* exists its returns something like that if someone send a request for /12345/json

```
{ "jobId": ["12345", "json"] }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This sent me a step forward.